# How to terminate input as a list when a negative integer is entered? (python)

Tags: python, list, input

How to terminate input in a list when a negative integer is entered?

I tried the following method to read the inputs but I can't think of a way to make it terminate when a negative integer is entered.

```
    a = [ int(n) for n in (raw_input("Enter input- ")).split() ]
```

The question asks to read (more than 7) integers from the user and swap the maximum with the minimum, second maximum with second minimum and third maximum with third minimum.

Is there a way to replace more than one item in a list or a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list comprehension` is not the right tool for the job. You should just write a loop like this

```
a = []
while True:
    n = int(raw_input("Enter input- "))
    if n < 0:
        break
    a.append(n)
```

If the values are all given on one line:

```
a = []
nums = raw_input("Enter input- ")
for n in nums.split():
    n = int(n)
    if n < 0:
        break
    a.append(n)
```

Comment: But the inputs should be entered in a line with space as the delimiter. For example- `Enter input - 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 -1  The ouptput is= 9 8 7 3 4 5 6 2 1 0`

Comment: Thank you. Is there a method to replace more than one item at a time? Or is there any method to swap the maximums with the minimums?